# How normalize the size of column title of extjs grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, sencha-touch

I have a grid in my app. Grid is launched by the handler of button and a grid is launched like a item inside tab. All are ok, but columns title looks like that: 
[image]

so columns title so hight and havn't names. If I setup layout'fit' in tab element :

```
...tab items//{ xtype: 'panel',
    layout:'fit',
    title: 'RENTERS',
    cls:'header-cls',
    items:[{
            type:'rentlist'
                },{//some more tab items...
```

I see ONLY columns titles:

[image]

How I can fix it? How to do view of columns titles normal, like in a sencha example?)

Comment: when i open one from tabs with grid i se warning message in debuger : Warning, size detected (calc(100% - 16px)) not a valid property value on Element.addUnits.